# Integrals: Areas Between Curves related problem.

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area of the shaded region.

[image]

So far I figured
$$A=\int _{-1}^0x^2\ \mathrm dx - \int _{-1}^0x^{\frac{1}{3}}\ \mathrm dx + \int _0^1\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}} - x^2\right)\ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Have you put ANY work into this? Any?

Comment: @Thomas it's a photograph of his screen.

Comment: The (gray) shaded region is $960\text{px} \cdot 543\text{px} = 521280\text{px}^2$

Comment: @AlexR - I LOLd when I read that.

Comment: @Clarinetist Couldn't resist ^^

Comment: Yes, so far what i understand is, A= $\int _{-1}^0x^2dx\:-\:\int _{-1}^0x^{\frac{1}{3}}\:dx\:+\:\int _0^1\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\:-\:x^2\right)dx$

Comment: @ZihanIbrahim - That actually looks correct. Could you show your integration work as well?

Comment: @ZihanIbrahim Could you comment on the answer provided to give feedback if it helps you or if it needs some additional information for you to be understood?

Comment: Yeah, your equation seems right. I also tried with this equation before, did something wrong while calculating the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
The area is defined by
$$A = \int_{-1}^1 |x^2 - \sqrt[3]x|\ \mathrm dx = \int_{-1}^0 x^2 - \sqrt[3]x\ \mathrm dx + \int_0^1 \sqrt[3]x - x^2\ \mathrm dx$$
as you correctly noticed.
Now use $\int_a^b x^k \ \mathrm dx = \left. \frac1{k+1} x^{k+1} \right|_a^b$ for any $k\ne -1$ (including $k = \frac13$ !)

Comment: @UserX It's outside of the semantics, $\frac13 !$ isn't properly defined anyways. I like to keep it that way. Added a space to separate it a little more, though.